# How can I achieve DynamoDB Pagination Same as SQL/MYSQL(Total count of items and I can jump to any other page) in C#

Tags: c#, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

how to implement pagination using DynamoDB in c# same as SQL/MYSQL.

I have check document for ScanRequest and QueryRequest that one is working perfectly fine.

But I need Pagination same as we all do in SQL/MYSQL like in initial call I need total number of item count and page wise records and easily I can jump to any other page also.

So anyone can suggest good solution or any alternative solution?

Thank you in advance.

```
Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> lastKeyEvaluated = null;
            do
            {
                var request = new ScanRequest
                {
                    TableName = "Test",
                    Limit = 5,
                    ExclusiveStartKey = lastKeyEvaluated
                };
                var response = await Client.ScanAsync(request);
                lastKeyEvaluated = response.LastEvaluatedKey;

            }
            while (lastKeyEvaluated.Count != 0);




            Dictionary<string, Condition> conditions = new Dictionary<string, Condition>();
            // Title attribute should contain the string "Adventures"
            Condition titleCondition = new Condition();
            titleCondition.ComparisonOperator = ComparisonOperator.EQ;
            titleCondition.AttributeValueList.Add(new AttributeValue { S = "Company#04" });
            conditions["PK"] = titleCondition;


            var request = new QueryRequest();
            request.Limit = 2;
            request.ExclusiveStartKey = null;
            request.TableName = "Test";
            request.KeyConditions = conditions;

            var result = await Client.QueryAsync(request);
```

Comment: DynamoDB isn't really designed for that

Comment: Oh any workaround we can do?

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB supports an [entirely different type of pagination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html).  The concept of page number, offset, etc. is another paradigm from the SQL database world that has no parallel in DynamoDB.  However, pagination *is* supported, just not the way many expect.

You may want to consider changing how your client application paginates to accommodate.  If you have a small amount of information to paginate (e.g. under 1MB of data), you might consider passing it to the client and letting the client implement the pagination (e.g. page 4 of 15).

If you have too much data to paginate client-side, you may want to consider updating your client application to accommodate how DynamoDB paginates (e.g. using `LastEvaluatedKey` and `ExclusiveStartKey`).